# How can I synchronise kmix and alsamixer volumes at maximum?

Tags: audio, kde, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-volume

Occasionally, I can increase kmix's volume to its maximum (using the volume hotkeys), but the sound is still very quiet. I can open up `alsamixer`, and see `Master` at ~8%, even though kmix's volume is 100%. If I change kmix's volume, I can see similar changes in `Master`, but only up to ~8% maximum.

I can manually increase `alsamixer`'s `Master`. This fixes the problem for a reasonable amount of time; changing kmix's volume results in similar changes in `Master` up to its maximum. However this fix seems to revert in a seemingly random and non-reproducible way (perhaps after a restart?).

**Is there a way to ensure that setting kmix to maximum results in `alsamixer` at maximum?**

I'm not sure if it's related, but when I change the volume in kmix, `alsamixer`'s `PCM` varies seemingly randomly from 100 to 98 and 99, and `Headphone` goes from 0 (at 0% kmix) to 55 (at 5% kmix) to 100 (≥10% kmix). As stated above, `Master` increases with changes in kmix.

Plasma 5.3 (but I think I saw it in KDE 4) in Arch Linux

Comment: This appears to be a problem with PulseAudio's juggling of multiple mixer controls. Try asking on the [PA mailing list](http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/pulseaudio-discuss).

Comment: Thanks @CL. I'll give this question a few more days, then try the mailing list.